# Changing styles on the current page's menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the following code

```
<style>
    .navbar .nav a.current {color:#3598fe; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('.primary-nav a').each(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).attr('href') === window.location.pathname) {
                jQuery(this).addClass('current');
            }
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

This part in body

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can someone help me with the right code to change to color of active hyperlink?

Comment: What's not working? 

@Scott, that doesn't address the apparent goal here, which is to apply a class to the current page's menu item.

Comment: @isherwood The question clearly asks about the **active** state. CSS is already in place for the "current" state. You're doing a lot of defending to an ambiguous question which isn't yours. How about letting the Original Poster decide what does and does not work?

Comment: And that was clearly (at least to me) a language issue. "Active" in this case means the current page.

Comment: @isherwood yes your right by active I meant the current page, and using css .nav a:active {} is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$('ul.nav a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('href') === window.location.hash;
}).addClass('current');
```

[Proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hjZXE/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use jquery for this just use this css

```
.nav a {}
.nav a:active {}
```

Yeah I see what he wanted, David Thomas solution seems to do the trick

Comment: This doesn't address the problem. Look more closely at the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is an option you can use if you don't want to get your hands dirty in jQuery. (I would recommend finding a better option later on as in-line styles are not the way to go)

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
  <li><a class="nav navhome" href="#Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav navcontact" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav navabout" href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you would add an in-line style on each page of what ever style you want it to alter.

```
<style>
  .nav a.navhome {color:#ff7200; }
</style>
```

This would change the current page's class to over write the color of the text.

Like I said earlier this is a solution but I would advise you to learn some jQuery to make it more current and fluent later down the road.